# How does a ClickOnce application know where to check for an upgrade?

Tags: c#, deployment, .net-3.5, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that is set to "Online Only". In other words, the `.appref-ms` file does not come down to the client (this file carries point-of-origin information).

However, the ClickOnce application uses the `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment` class to check to see where there is an update available.

How does the application know where to check for an update, if the `.appref-ms` file does not come down to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cdf-ms files and executable manifests are going to a client anyway. When ClickOnce launches, the manifests are telling it where it can get updates from.

They are in `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Apps` for Windows 7 and `C:\Documents and Settings\USER_NAME\Local Settings\Apps\2.0` for earlier versions.

Comment: I bet using System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment class

Comment: The locations are different for, say, a Spanish version of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Check registry: `HCU > Software > Microsoft > Windows > Uninstall > #yourappid# > UrlUpdateInfo`